# Can we show markdown preview continuously for background markdown file in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

In VS Code, If my markdown file is not opened in editor, still I want to show its preview panel on the right side. Can this be done?

If our active file is markdown file then only its preview option is available.

Is there any other way for my requirement?
I want solution for visual code only.

Markdown preview available only for the active files. I want to show preview panel continuously for the background markdown files in vs code.

Comment: open the markdown file, show the preview, close the markdown file, the preview stays visible until you open a markdown file, at least when I do a side preview view in column 2

Answer (score 0):

You can open it in the right editor group using the `Markdown: Open Preview to the Side` command in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette), which is bound by default to <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>v</kbd>. See also the `Markdown: Open Locked Preview to the Side`, and [the user docs for the Markdown Preview](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_markdown-preview). There's also a button to do this at the top right of the editor group's tab strip ([image]/[image]).

Alternatively, You can open the previous as a new tab using the `Markdown: Open Preview` command, which is bound by default to <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and then drag the tab to the right side put it in a different editor group.